# CI & CD integartion for Xamarin.Android application with VSTS

Tags: git, xamarin, continuous-integration, licensing, cd

I am new to the CI & CD integration with VSTS.

I planned to do this for Xamarin.android application as it is acquired by Microsoft.

I am able to push my codes to the VSTS from the visual studio successfully but facing problem when building the codes from the build definition.

In the "Activate Xamarin Licence" step , it asked for the Xamarin License email and password.

I tried to give the credentials of mine from  https://store.xamarin.com/ but getting error as "Failed to activate Xamarin License" {"code" :-3 , "Message" : "Could not look up activation code"}

[image]

Also, tried with licensed MSDN account but still no luck.

Requesting anybody who have worked earlier on this to help.

Thanks & regards, 
Anil

Comment: What are you using the respective Xamarin License for? There's not a requirement for licenses anymore unless you had previous Enterprise features or you are using the Component store. Can you simply skip this license check step?

Comment: Thanks Jon. It is building successfully after removing the Xamarin License activation step.

Comment: Ill add this as an answer real quick.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to activate, do you have a valid subscription? You should be able to get to it from https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription.

[image: Xamarin Account Subscription]

What does your build step look like?
Disable the activation and see if it works anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using the respective Xamarin License for? There's not a requirement for licenses anymore unless you had previous Enterprise features or you are using the Component store. Can you simply skip this license check step? This should work given there's not a license check step anymore while building.